Node.Js ZKlib getRealTimeLogs not working
I use zklib library, npm link https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zklib.
I call the function and declare it as follows:
zkInstance.getRealTimeLogs((data)=>{ // do something when some checkin console.log(data) })
But no results returned. Someone please help me, please.
I want to connect to the device and when my fingerprint is scanned, the data will be transmitted to me in real time. I have tried many examples and libraries like node-zklib or zklib but to no avail.

Do you point out the problems? I face the same problem.
